# converting local time to UTC time(datetime object)

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to convert the local time to "UTC" time.

Followed this guide: [How do I convert local time to UTC in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79797/how-do-i-convert-local-time-to-utc-in-python)

But issue here is with the type of date which we giving here.

```
import pytz, datetime
local = pytz.timezone ("America/Los_Angeles")
naive = datetime.datetime.strptime ("2001-2-3 10:11:12", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
local_dt = local.localize(naive, is_dst=None)
utc_dt = local_dt.astimezone (pytz.utc)
```

In the above code input is "2001-2-3 10:11:12" (string), But in my case it will be a datetime object.

```
begin = begin.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
```

Someone let me know how we can achieve the conversion here.

Answer (score 0):

Your string format needs a bit of a modification. You just need the leading zeros in your month and day:

```
import pytz, datetime
local = pytz.timezone("America/Los_Angeles")
naive = datetime.datetime.strptime ("2001-02-03 10:11:12", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
local_dt = local.localize(naive)
utc_dt = local_dt.astimezone(pytz.utc)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input (`begin`) is not a time string but it is a [naive (no timezone info)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5802108/4279) `datetime` object already then drop `datetime.strptime()` line (that parses the time string into `datetime` object) from the example. To convert a given [naive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5802108/4279) `datetime` object that represents local time to utc:

```
import pytz    # $ pip install pytz
import tzlocal # $ pip install tzlocal

local_timezone = tzlocal.get_localzone()
local_dt = local_timezone.localize(begin, is_dst=None)
utc_dt = local_dt.astimezone(pytz.utc)
```