# PDT to UTC converted datetime object format

Tags: python, datetime

I need to find the UTC equivalent time for the PDT time.

So that I have implemented the code which is as follows:

```
        utc = pytz.utc
        local = pytz.timezone ("America/Los_Angeles")
        begin_localize = local.localize(begin)
        begin = begin_localize.astimezone(utc)

        end_localize = local.localize(end)
        end = end_localize.astimezone(utc)
```

It is generating the output as follows:

```
2016-04-02 07:00:00+00:00
```

Type is as follows:

```
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Even though it is working fine, My backend needs a value which in the format as follows:

```
2016-04-02 00:00:00
```

Also should be of type type 'datetime.datetime'.

Someone help me with the way of achieving the same.

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse an object such as `datetime.datetime` and its printable representation such as `'2016-04-02 00:00:00'` string. You could get any format you like using [`.strftime()` method](http://strftime.org).

> My backend needs a value which in the format as follows:
>   2016-04-02 00:00:00
>   Also should be of type type 'datetime.datetime'.

The comment suggest that you want a [*naive*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5802108/4279) datetime object. To remove the timezone info, you could use `.replace()` method:

```
naive_dt = begin_localize.replace(tzinfo=None)
```

You could get the naive object that represents utc time directly:

```
# <local time> == <utc time> + <utc offset> by definition
# <utc time> = <local time> - <utc offset>
naive_utc_dt = naive_local - local_timezone.utcoffset(naive_local)
```

Note: the time that `naive_local` represents may be an ambiguous or even non-existent in the local timezone (e.g., during DST transitions). Pass `is_dst` parameter to disambiguate if necessary.