# Converting UTC datetime to UK datetime using tz.localize in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to convert a UTC date/time to 'Europe/London' timezone. I have tried using tz.localize using the date but I am told the datetime is not naive. If I try to remove the the timezone I still get the same error.

Fundamentally, I am trying to get this date:
**04/05/2016 15:00**
to become this date:
**04/05/2016 14:00**

My code is as follows where I am parsing through the date using iso8601.

```
date = 2016-05-04 15:00:00+00:00
fix_pars = iso8601.parse_date(str(date))
```

I have tried used pytz.localize but with no success as it doesn't like the fact my date already has a timezone set.

I find the documentation on this really confusing. All I want is the magic function that takes a date and converts based on a requested timezone. What function am I best to use?

Comment: `date = 2016-05-04 15:00:00+00:00` is not valid Python. Why do you call `str(date)`? What is `type(date)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `tz.localize` with utc timezone because it has a fixed utc offset (zero). If you have a [timezone-aware](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5802108/4279) datetime object (as its text representation suggests) then to convert it to `Europe/London` timezone:

```
london_dt = aware_dt.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Europe/London'))
```

that is all.

Answer (score 14):

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime
tz = pytz.timezone('UTC')
naive_time = datetime.strptime('2016-04-05 15:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
tz_time = tz.localize(naive_time)
london_tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')
london_time = tz_time.astimezone(london_tz)
```

And here are my outputs:

```
>>> print tz_time
2016-04-05 15:00:00+00:00
>>> print london_time
2016-04-05 16:00:00+01:00
```

Comment: Amended my code to:
date = '2016-06-11 16:00:00+00:00'
naive_time = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
tz_time = tz.localize(naive_time)
london_time = tz_time.astimezone(london_tz)
But I get...   
data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: :00+00:00

Comment: @LemusThelroy You would have to convert that to a string then remove the timezone from it: `str(theTime)[:-6]` and then if you want to update the `naive_time` variable to include the seconds as well `naive_time = datetime.strptime(str(theTime)[:-6], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

Comment: If I wanted to convert the london_time to dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm format, what function should I use? I will then go and read the documentation on this.

Comment: @LemusThelroy You can still use the [strptime](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strptime.htm) method. You'll just have to edit the formating string to do it: `naive_time = datetime.strptime('05/04/2016 15:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')`

Comment: Hi I want to convert Asia  honk Kong time to new York time zone but I am getting wrong hours.normally there is difference between both is 12 hrs but I am getting difference as 20hrs