# Timezone Conversion From UTC to new time zone

Tags: python, timezone, timestamp

I'm having a bunch of trouble converting UTC to a new time zone in python.

The data is originally a string brought in and successfully to converted to UTC as such:

```
df['order delivery time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['order delivery time'])
```

Next I attempt to write a function like this:

```
eastern = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
central = pytz.timezone('US/Central')
pacific = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')

def change_tz(time, region):
    if region == 'sf':
        return time.astimezone(pytz.timezone(pacific))
    elif region == 'chi':
        return time.astimezone(pytz.timezone(central))
    elif region == 'nyc':
        return time.astimezone(pytz.timezone(eastern))
```

Then apply:

```
 df['order delivery time ADJUSTED'] = df.apply(lambda row: change_tz(row['order delivery time'], row['region']), axis=1)
```

I get this error:

```
 AttributeError: ("'US/Central' object has no attribute 'upper'", u'occurred at index 0')
```

I've also tried lines like:

```
 if region == 'sf':
      return datetime.fromtimestamp(time, tz='US/Pacific')
```

And:

```
 if region == 'sf':
      return tz.fromutc(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(time).replace(tzinfo='US/Pacific'))
```

Please help me convert the time zone! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've had success using pytz and dateutil.parser in the past:

```
import pytz
import dateutil.parser

date_needed = dateutil.parser.parse(request.POST.get("date_needed"))
item.date_needed = pytz.timezone("America/Phoenix").localize(date_needed, is_dst=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

> AttributeError: ("'US/Central' object has no attribute 'upper'", u'occurred at index 0')

`central` is already a `pytz.timezone` object. Don't pass it to `pytz.timezone()`—use it directly.

It is not clear what `time` variable is in your case (`type(time)`).

If `time` is a float number representing Unix time then you could get the corresponding timezone-aware datetime object in a given timezone using:

```
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(unix_time, central)
```

If `time` is already a [timezone-aware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27596917/4279) datetime object representing time in UTC then to convert it to a given timezone:

```
dt = dt_utc.astimezone(central)
```

You can use the `tz_convert()` method to convert pandas objects to convert tz-aware data to another time zone:

```
ts_utc.tz_convert(central)
```