# Check if datetime object in pandas has a timezone?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone

I'm importing data into pandas and want to remove any timezones – if they're present in the data. If the data has a time zone, the following code works successfully:

```py
col = "my_date_column"
df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col]).dt.tz_localize(None) # We don't want timezones...
```

If the data does not contain a timezone, I'd like to use the following code:

```py
df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col])
```

My issue is that **I'm not sure how to test for timezone in the datetime object / series**.

Comment: You can apply `.dt.tz_localize(None)` to all columns if there is no timezone it doesn't change this column.

Comment: are you sure you want to localize to None? you could also convert to None, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62656878/10197418)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you have a column of type datetime, you can check the `tzinfo` of each timestamp in the column. It's basically described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802108/how-to-check-if-a-datetime-object-is-localized-with-pytz) (although this is not specific to `pytz`). Ex:

```
import pandas as pd

# example series:
s = pd.Series([
        pd.Timestamp("2020-06-06").tz_localize("Europe/Berlin"), # tzinfo defined
        pd.Timestamp("2020-06-07") # tzinfo is None
        ])

# s
# 0    2020-06-06 00:00:00+02:00
# 1          2020-06-07 00:00:00
# dtype: object
  
# now find a mask which is True where the timestamp has a timezone:
has_tz = s.apply(lambda t: t.tzinfo is not None)

# has_tz
# 0     True
# 1    False
# dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 6):

This builds upon the [prior answer by FObersteiner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62750241/).

If the column is of type `datetime64[ns]`, use [`Series.dt.tz`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz.html):

```
col.dt.tz is None
```

If the column is of type `object` of `pd.Timestamp`, it doesn't support `.dt`, so use [`Timestamp.tz`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.tz.html) instead:

```
col.apply(lambda t: t.tz is None).all()
```

Comment: I think this is the more efficient solution (`dt` accessor) if you only require True/False for the whole Series

Answer (score 1):

## Inspect the `tz` attribute:

To check if a Pandas Timestamp is timezone aware, you can inspect its tz attribute. If the tz attribute is None, the Timestamp is timezone-naive. If it contains a timezone object (like a pytz timezone), then the Timestamp is timezone-aware.

Here's a simple way to check:

```
import pandas as pd

# Example Timestamp
timestamp = pd.Timestamp('2024-01-01 12:00:00')

# Check if the Timestamp is timezone aware
if timestamp.tz is not None:
    print("The timestamp is timezone aware.")
else:
    print("The timestamp is timezone naive.")
```

It isn't clear exactly what you want to do in your question, however if you simply want to inspect to see if the timestamps are timezone aware, you can do this:

```
for timestamp in df['my_date_column']:
    if timestamp.tz is not None:
        print(timestamp.tz)
```