# How to define a Pandera DataFrame schema for validating and parsing datetime columns?

Tags: pandas, validation, pandera

I have a csv that contains datetime columns and I want to use Pandera to validate the columns and parse them to the correct format. An example value in the column would be: `2023-02-04T00:39:00+00:00`.

This is currently parsed in pandas to the right format using the following python code:

```
column = pd.to_datetime(column, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
column = column.dt.tz_convert("Europe/Amsterdam")
```

I would want to define a pandera DataFrame schema such that parsing is handled "automatically" when I read the csv with the following code:

```
schema = DataFrameSchema(
    {
        "datetime_column": Column()  # how to implement the above here??
    },
    strict=True,
    coerce=False,
)

df = pd.read_csv(src, dtype={col: str(dtype) for col, dtype in schema.dtypes.items()})
schema.validate(df)
```

I already use the above approach for simple types like string, ints, etc. But how would I do this for DateTime types (usually tz-aware)?

There is not a lot of documentation so I couldn't figure it out from the online documentation so far.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62748241/check-if-datetime-object-in-pandas-has-a-timezone

Comment: @Jose Yes, I can use python to do the work but I was wondering if I can do the validation and parsing using Pandera (I like the idea of defining and validating the data format separately)

Answer (score 0):

Pandera allows you to create new custom data types to include in the schema [(Link)](https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dtypes.html#logical-data-types). If you want to use a datetime type to coerce a column with specific format, you can do it using [pandas_engine.DateTime](https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/pandera.engines.pandas_engine.DateTime.html#pandera-engines-pandas-engine-datetime), importing all the columns in the .csv as string and after that, coercing the schema. Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandera as pa
from pandera.engines import pandas_engine

df = pd.read_csv(r"test.csv", dtype=str)
print(df.dtypes) #All cols as object type

schema = pa.DataFrameSchema(
            {"date_col": pa.Column(
                pandas_engine.DateTime(to_datetime_kwargs = {"format":"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"},
                                       tz = "Europe/Amsterdam")
                ),
            "col_1": pa.Column("object"),
            "col_2": pa.Column("int32")},
            coerce=True)
# Validating and coercing data types
new_df = schema.validate(df)
print(new_df.dtypes) #New dtypes for all cols
```